# What is the right way of using Saver parameter `keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours`?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to save my tensorflow variables every 5 hours during training.

So, according to [Tensorflow Saver doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver#class_saver), I constructed `saver = Saver` with parameter `keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours=5`, and called `saver.save()` for every step of learning. So what I expected was the saver module somehow detects the time passed after starting the training, and save the model every 5 hours, instead of actually saving model for every step where it is called.

Below simplifies how i used the feature.

```
sess = tf.Session()
model = Model(sess)
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=5,
                       keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours=5)

step_count = 0
max_step = 10000

while step_count < max_step:
    model.train()
    saver.save(sess, 'model', global_step=step_count)
    step_count += 1
```

However, I found out that by doing this way, the model is saved every time when the function is called.

I guess I'm missing something or not using it in proper way.
I want to know the proper way of using the feature of the tensorflow Saver.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

max_to_keep parameter specifies that a checkpoint would be saved every time but no more than 5 checkpoints would be kept at a time.

keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours on the other hand specifies that every N hours a checkpoint would be saved and will not be deleted or overwritten.

So, I would recommend using keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours in case your training takes a long time and might diverge. So if the last 5 chechpoints become equally useless you can revert to the one of at most N hours ago.

Comment: so setting `keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours` to 5 does not behave that the model would be saved every 5 hours, such as wait for 5 hours to be pass from starting the process and save the model when the duration becomes 5 hours long. Instead, it keeps every checkpoint saved during 5 hours and prevent them from overwritten or deleted. Am I understanding it correct?

Comment: it does not sound right. it creates a checkpoint every time save() is called. if there are more than 5 checkpoints - the older one will be deleted. But, it every 5 hours it will leave one checkpoint untouched in addition to these 5

Comment: so according to my setting, there should be 5 latest checkpoints saved every time `save()` is called, plus 1 checkpoint which is saved every 5 hours, and in total that makes 6 checkpoints.